# How to write regular expression if the reference to the sentence is not clear

Tags: regex

I'm learning NLP and I meet a problem when I tried to use regular expression to solve the following questions:

> How much did A drop?
>
> How much did B drop?

And the giving sentences are below:

> 1. At about 3:45, A careened to still another limit, of 30 points down, and trading was locked again.
>
> 2.Futures traders say A was signaling that B could fall as much as 200 points.
>
> 3.A had plunged 12 points

I tried to extract the correct answers `30 and 12`, and my regular expression code is:

```
'\s?A (.+ )?(fall|drop|go\sdown|down|fell|plunged)(\sas\smuch\sas)? (\d+)'
```

Obviously, it's not correct. it will give the answer `"200"` to the 'A' and miss `'30'`.
Could someone please teach me how to write Regex based on this situation?
Any response will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Regex alone can't really do this AFAIK.  You need some sort of text parser, which can intelligently look for keywords indicating that the number you want is in vicinity.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If I ignore sentence No.1, is there any possible writing a regex that give only 200 to B and 12 to A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that the text you want to match has the format `Letter ... VERB ... [0-9]+ points`, then we can try using the following pattern:

```
\b[A-Z]\b.*?(?:fall|drop|go\sdown|down|fell|plunged|careened).*?(\d+) points
```

### Demo